# Detect Dimming on Android Watch

Tags: android, screen, wear-os

I have searched around and looked for a way to detect the watch dimming.  I want to write some code to change a custom watch faces color when the screen dims.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this abstract Activity to detect the watch dimming (implementing DisplayManager.DisplayListener).

```
public abstract class WatchFaceActivity extends Activity implements DisplayManager.DisplayListener {

private DisplayManager displayManager;

public abstract void onScreenDim();
public abstract void onScreenAwake();

public void onWatchFaceRemoved() {
}

public void onScreenOff() {
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    displayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    displayManager.registerDisplayListener(this, null);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    displayManager.unregisterDisplayListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onDisplayRemoved(int displayId) {
    onWatchFaceRemoved();
}

@Override
public void onDisplayAdded(int displayId) {
}

@Override
public void onDisplayChanged(int displayId) {
    switch (displayManager.getDisplay(displayId).getState()) {
        case Display.STATE_DOZING:
            onScreenDim();
            break;
        case Display.STATE_OFF:
            onScreenOff();
            break;
        default:
            onScreenAwake();
            break;
    }
}}
```

More infos here: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-custom-android-wear-watch-face/120